# How can I fire the unload method when closing the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onbeforeunload, onunload

**Observed scenarios:**

1. When closing the browser, the `beforeunload` event is fired but the `unload` event isn't fired.
2. When closing the tab, both the `beforeunload` event and the `unload` event are fired.

**Question:**

How can I fire the `unload` method when closing the browser?

**Code:**

```
    var inFormOrLink = false;
    var flag = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
               return "You are about to close the window";
        });
        $(window).on("unload", function () {
            if (!inFormOrLink)
                window.open('../Account/Login?admin=admin', "_blank");
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {

            if (!flag) {
                inFormOrLink = true;
                $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
                $(window).unbind('unload');
            }
            else {
                // inFormOrLink = false;
                $(window).bind('beforeunload');
                $(window).bind('unload');
            }
        });

        $(".btn").click(function () {

            if (!flag) {
                inFormOrLink = true;
                $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
                $(window).unbind('unload');
            }
            else {
                inFormOrLink = false;
                flag = false;
                $(window).bind('beforeunload');
                $(window).bind('unload');
            }

        });
        $("body").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 116 || e.which == 117) {
                inFormOrLink = true;
            }
            else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 82) {
                inFormOrLink = true;
            }
            else if (e.which == 8) {
                var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
                inFormOrLink = true;
                if (tag != "input") {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            else {
                inFormOrLink = false;
                $(window).bind('unload');
            }
        });
    });
```

'

Answer (score 0):

The `onunload` event theoretically should run in the case you mentioned, however, there are many browsers and each is implemented by a different team. Since you observed a bug in a few browsers, I suggest that you should attach the event handlers to `beforeunload` instead of `unload`. In that case you work around the problem. Another possiblity is to run the `unload` event, like this:

```
$(window).unload();
```